# How to draw polyline perpendicular to another polyline using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I've drawn a polygon and I want to draw a perpendicular line to this polygon.  I found the `computeOffset` function of google maps api from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839883/drawing-a-line-in-google-maps-perpendicular-to-two-points), but I'm using Leaflet.  Is there an equivalent function in Leaflet?

Here is a screenshot of drawing the polyline.

[image]

I want to draw the perpendicular line that passes through the start point of the drawing polyline (the start point is marked with a marker on the screenshot).  The expected result is like this.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Leaflet has no equivalent.

You'll have to resort to a geodetic utility library for this kind of calculations. See [cheap-ruler](https://github.com/mapbox/cheap-ruler), [geographiclib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/js/) and [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/).

Comment: Thank you @IvanSanchez, I will make research for this libraries. I have a question, czn I use one of this libraries with Leaflet without any problem?

Comment: I can't find function for this issue in this libraries :(

Comment: Look harder. `computeOffset` is pretty much geographiclib's inverse geodesic problem resolver, and your original problem seems to be covered by TurfJS's `pointonline`.

Define your problem better if you want a better pointer.

Comment: I don't think that **pointonline** will do the job, my issue is I have a polyline drawing on map and I want to draw another polyline which is perpendicular to the first polyline. Now I'm trying to do some mathematics, I hope that you can help me to find a useful function. Thank you

Comment: Define your problem better. Explain these things in your original question. Add examples, drawings, expected output for a given input. It's very hard to guess what you *exactly* are trying to do.

Comment: No, it's not clear. Show a set of inputs, and the expected result. And pay attention to the nomenclature of "polyline" and "line segment"

Comment: OK, clearer now. You need to solve the inverse geodetic problem (with geographiclib's `Inverse` or cheap-ruler's `bearing`), add 90 degrees to the bearing, then solve the direct geodetic problem (with geographiclib's `Direct` or cheap-ruler's `destination`)

Comment: Thank you @IvanSanchez  for this indication, finaly I used bearing and I add to it 90 degrees as you said to get the perpendicular line, thank you for youe help :)